# What's the difference between variables defined with and without the 'var' keyword?

Tags: game-maker

I've been making my way through several tutorials on GameMaker: Studio at this point, and I've been trying to keep track of various aspects of the code used in them. One thing, however, confused me.

I have noticed that it's possible to define new variables in GM:S either with or without using the `var` keyword. I'm aware that you can use the `var` keyword to define multiple variables in one line, for example `var xx, yy;` (and, of course, defining null variables), but other than that, is there a particular reason why some variables don't need to use `var`? Is it all to do with functionality, or what? When, in that case, should I use `var` other than the example provided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables declared with the `var` keyword are local variables, whereas variables declared without `var` are instance variables. More information on scope: https://yoyogames.com/tech_blog/41

Answer (score 0):

If you say `var test = 0`, it is a local variable, and will be deleted at the end of the event.

If you say `test = 0`, it will be stored in that object until the game ends, or the object is deleted.

If you say `globalvar test = 0`, it will be stored until the game ends, and will not be deleted with the object. It can also be accessed in another object without typing `otherObject.test`.

Comment: Please do not use offensive language in your answer.